# Choosing a Flavor Based on BuildTypes

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, flutter, build

I am setting up an Android app that points to a particular Firebase environment based on the build type:

- Debug build -> dev Firebase environment
- Release build -> prod Firebase environment

I followed this [guideline](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects) and ended up having some productFlavors in my gradle file and stored `google-services.json` for both environment in **android/app/src/{env}**.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
}

flavorDimensions "env"
productFlavors {
    dev {
        dimension "env"
    }

    prod {
        dimension "env"
    }
}
```

The issue is, now I need to specify `--flavor` when running `flutter build apk`.

Is there a way to automatically determine the flavor from the build type, e.g., running `flutter run` will point to **dev**, and running `flutter run --release` will point to **prod**?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `--flavor`. The [official documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/flavors) lists other blog articles which goes into details on setting up your IDE etc.

If you are using a terminal to `flutter run` maybe a hacky approach would be an alias for `flutter run --flavor app1` etc.